# Is it possible to list all hidden lemmas of a proof?

Tags: philosophy, formal-proofs, meta-math, formal-systems

I'm studying Imre Lakatos' *Proofs and Refutations* for my master's thesis. Currently I address the concept of hidden lemmas, which I understand to mean unstated assumptions of a mathematical proof, which may turn out to be faulty, leading to counterexamples.

When contemplating hidden lemmas I postulated the following metamathematical statement: "It is impossible to explicitly list all hidden lemmas of a mathematical proof." or an alternate formulation of the statement as: "It is impossible to explicitly list all assumptions of a formal deduction."

1. Are these two statements equal in the context of formal proofs?

For context, I'm primarily looking at mathematical formalism as it was in the beginning of the 20th century under the influence of David Hilbert and at Lakatos' criticism of it.

I am aware of Lakatos' interest in informal proofs, but for the sake of the argument I want to consider if a system where all assumptions are listable is possible. This leads to a follow-up question:

2. Are there any logical systems where it is possible to list all assumptions of a formal deduction and to prove that such a list is complete?

My hunch is that even if such a list could be constructed, proving its completeness would be undecidable in the system itself. However, my own knowledge is not enough to prove this hunch, answer the first question or to give an example of or refute the statement implied in the second question.

Comment: Related: [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles).

Comment: The key-point of formalization is exactly to "put on the table" explicitly all that is needed. But... every formal system must be described and explained and this implies the use of natural language (or mathematical jargon): this is the meta- context. It is impossible to avoid it.

Comment: Quite a significant amount of mathematics has been formalised using [proof assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property).  No lemmas are hidden in such formalisations.

Comment: But what Lakatos discusses are example of Lemma that can be formulated in the language of the theory and that has been used implicitly or in an unnoticed way (well-know examples from Euclid's Elements)

Comment: Check out any metamath theorem, for example http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/znq.html. On the bottom, you can see all axioms used in its proof, all definitions, and by actually looking at each proof step, if you open the theorem the step references and look at its proof and so on, you can see all theorems used.